# Totally confused about this.next() in Meteor iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I upgraded to Meteor 1.0, installed the latest iron-router package, tried to run my app and got this nice warning in my console log:

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in
>   an onBeforeAction?

So I tried to modify my routes according to the new version.

```
this.route('gamePage', {
        path: '/game/:slug/',
        onBeforeAction: [function() {
            this.subscribe('singlePlayer', this.params.slug).wait();
            var singlePlayer = this.data();
            if (singlePlayer) {
                if (singlePlayer.upgrade) {
                    this.subscribe('upgrades', this.params.slug).wait();
                    this.next();
                }
                this.next();
            }
            this.next();
        }],
        data: function() {
            return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        },
        waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug)]}
    });
```

How can I fix this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing all the `.wait()`s and removing the array around your onBefore function.

With the new API `this.next()` replaces `.wait()`.

Comment: Thank you! That works! Do I need 3 x `this.next()` or just once at the end of the function?

Comment: You may not need it for the first `if`. Give it a try and report back.

Comment: This worked for me:
`if (singlePlayer) {
                if (singlePlayer.upgrade) {
                    this.subscribe('upgrades', this.params.slug).wait();
                }
            }
            this.next();`
Could you please explain where I should place `this.next()` in general? Trial-and-error method is a little bit frustrating.

Comment: Sorry about that. Basically you need it if your `onBefore` or `onRun` does not result in a `Router.go()` being ran. Which yours does not. IronRouter `onBefore` will run the first command it encounters then stop... unless you call `this.next()`. Then it will do the same thing (run then stop) until either you reach the end of the `onBefore/onRun` logic or a `Router.go` is called.