# Not found page pops up for a second - Meteor - iron - router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I upgraded my app to Meteor 1.0 and updated the my `router.js`, because I can't use `.wait()` [anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692789/totally-confused-about-this-next-in-meteor-iron-router). However, now my not found page pops up for just a second, before the 'real page' shows up. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
this.route('gamePage', {
        path: '/game/:slug/',
        onBeforeAction: [function() {
            this.subscribe('singlePlayer', this.params.slug);
            var singlePlayer = this.data();
            if (singlePlayer) {
                if (singlePlayer.upgrade) {
                    this.subscribe('upgrades', this.params.slug);
                }
            }
            this.next();
        }],
        data: function() {
            return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
        },
        waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug)]}
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of iron router? Also: why use array (square) brackets around the `onBeforeAction` callback? I haven't seen that syntax before. I've only used iron router 0.9.4, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `subscriptions` pattern instead.

```
this.route('gamePage', {
    path: '/game/:slug/',
    subscriptions: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('singlePlayer', this.params.slug);
    },
    onBeforeAction: function() {    
        var singlePlayer = this.data();
        if (singlePlayer) {
            if (singlePlayer.upgrade) {
                this.subscribe('upgrades', this.params.slug);
            }
        }
        this.next();
    },
    data: function() {
        return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
    },
    waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug)]}
});
```

However, it is important that you also include the `loading` plugin to take advantage of the `loadingTemplate`.

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate: 'loading' // general purpose loading template
});

// built in plugin.. surprisingly not clearly specified in current docs, but you can dive in the code for plugins. 
// https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/lib/plugins.js

Router.onBeforeAction('loading', { only: ['gamePage'] }); // only show loading for pages with subscriptions

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('gamePage',{
      //... your other options here ..
      loadingTemplate: 'gamePageLoading', // game Page dedicated loading markup.
  });
});
```

There's also the `this.ready()` pattern if you'd like to stay at your `onBeforeAction` implementation.

```
this.route('gamePage', {
    path: '/game/:slug/',
    onBeforeAction: [function() {
        this.subscribe('singlePlayer', this.params.slug);

        if(this.ready()) {
            var singlePlayer = this.data();
            if (singlePlayer) {
                if (singlePlayer.upgrade) {
                    this.subscribe('upgrades', this.params.slug);
                }
            }
            this.next();
        } else {
            this.render('loading');
        }

    }],
    data: function() {
        return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
    },
    waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug)]}
});
```

Source: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#subscriptions

I think this change was necessary because the `.wait` pattern was viewed as unnecessary chaining and is prone to (coding) errors. Additionally, explicitly handling the `.next()` when overriding `onBeforeAction` now ensures proper timing of this hook (and probably most, if not all other hooks).